# HQL Query left join and bean with array

Tags: java, arrays, left-join, hql, hibernate-onetomany

I have 2 tables with beans like above attached.

I build a little restful with spring with an output JSON file.

I did try to do a select with HQL language to filter 1 row for article **'046'**.

The output JSON come back 3 rows and not 1 rows like the data.

Someone can help me?

Thanks so much!

DATA:

```
Prelievo(id)   Row(Id)  Article
1082040        1        066   
1082040        2        066 
1082040        3        046
```

BEANS:

```
public class RighePrelievo implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ABAMNB")
private int id;

@Id
@Column(name = "ABALNB")
private int rigaPrelievo;

@Column(name = "ABAJCD")
private String articolo;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ABAMNB", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Prelievo prelievo;

 ...getter and setter

}



public class Prelievo implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "AHAMNB")
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "prelievo")
private List<RighePrelievo> righePrelievo = new ArrayList<>();



 ...getter and setter  
 }
```

HQL HIBERNATE QUERY:

```
 String articolo = "046";
List<Prelievo> firstFilterPrelievi = (List<Prelievo>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                        " select distinct p from "
                        + " Prelievo  p "
                        + " left join "
                        + " RighePrelievo r"
                        + " on p.id=r.id"
                        + " where "
                        + " r.articolo = :articolo "
                )
                .setParameter("articolo", articolo)
                .list();
```

OUTPUT JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1082040,
        "righePrelievo": [
            {
                "id": 1082040,
                "rigaPrelievo": 1,
                "articolo": "066"
            },
            {
                "id": 1082040,
                "rigaPrelievo": 2,
                "articolo": "066"
            },
            {
                "id": 1082040,
                "rigaPrelievo": 3,
                "articolo": "046"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You're returning a row af Prelievo entity, so you have a list under it, rapresented by 3 righePrelievo rows. Maybe you can return righePrelievo in your select field list

Comment: I write this: @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prelievo")
    private List<RighePrelievo> righePrelievo = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I added @JsonIgnore and now run fine.